# Срабатывание анимации, при наведении на внешний блок

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Есть анимация, я хочу обернуть во внешний блок и при наведении на внешний блок вызывалась эта анимация, как можно это сделать?

```css
.rectangle-button {
    border: 5px solid #FF4218;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    Width:155px;
    Height: 40px;
    margin-left:58px;
    margin-top:45px;
    margin-bottom:19px;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
    position: relative;
}
.rectangle-button:hover  {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-shadow: nthree;
}
.rectangle-button:hover:before {
    left: 0%;
    right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.rectangle-button:before{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    color: #000 !important;
    background: #FF4218;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 pl-0 zindex"><div class="rectangle-button">Купить</div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить стили таким образом, чтобы особая стилизация проводилась не по псевдоклассу `:hover` кнопки, а по родительскому.

В примере ниже я изменил верстку, добавив один класс `.example` для родительского элемента, чтобы было понятно, что я имею в виду.

```css
.rectangle-button {
  border: 5px solid #FF4218;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  Width: 155px;
  Height: 40px;
  margin-left: 58px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  position: relative;
}

.example:hover .rectangle-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: nthree;
}

.example:hover .rectangle-button:before {
  left: 0%;
  right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.rectangle-button:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  color: #000 !important;
  background: #FF4218;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.example {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 pl-0 zindex example">
  <div class="rectangle-button">Купить</div>
</div>
```